# How to test an XML result in Play 2.1.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am trying to write a test case for a controller method of Play 2.1.0. The method receives an XML object, does some stuff and returns OK or BAD_REQUEST depending on the XML, there is part of it:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Xml.class)
public static Result save() {
    Document dom = request().body().asXml();
    System.out.println(request().body());
    if (dom == null) {
        return badRequest(error.render("Se esperaba Xml"));
    } else {
        ...
```

When I try to test it with curl it works fine:

```
$ curl --header "Content-type: text/xml" --request POST --data '<gloo>Guillaume</gloo>' -verbose http://localhost:9000/api/xml/
* About to connect() to localhost port 9000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /api/xml/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:9000
> Accept: */*
> Referer: rbose
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 22
> 
* upload completely sent off: 22 out of 22 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 89
< 


* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><gloo>dd8d191c-8a27-4dad-a624-1c5a6a5d9d03</gloo>
```

But when I try to test it looks like I am passing a bad XML to the controller. This is my test case:

```
@Test
public void saveActionRespondsOkOnValidContent() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Result result = route(fakeRequest(POST, "/api/xml/")
                    .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml").withTextBody(
                            "<gloo>Probando el API xml</gloo>"));
            System.out.println(contentAsString(result));
            assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
            assertThat(contentType(result)).isEqualTo("text/xml");
            assertThat(contentAsString(result)).isNotEmpty();
        }
    });
}
```

And this is what I got when I run "play test":

```
...
DefaultRequestBody(None,None,None,None,None,None,true)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><gloo>Se esperaba Xml</gloo>
[error] Test api.XmlApiTests.saveActionRespondsOkOnValidContent failed: expected:<[2]00> but was:<[4]00>
...
```

First line is traced by the controller, saying there is no XML.
Second one is traced by the test case, saying the received error message.
And third one is my test case failing: I receive a BAD_REQUEST when I was waiting for an OK.

So my question (finally) is:
How can I write a test case that sends a valid XML to my method?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a method `withXmlBody` in `FakeRequest` as documented [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/java/index.html). Using that method instead of `withTextBody` should help.

Another thing to try (I haven't tested this myself) would be to change `Content-Type` to `application/xml`